# Element button must not appear as a descendant?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to validate m HTML code and it keeps giving me an error

> "the element (button) must not appear as a descendant of the (a) element"

This is what I have

```
<body>
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav_links">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="visit.html">Visit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <a class="cta" href="contact.html"><button>Contact</button></a>
    </header>
    </body>
```

What can I do to sort this?

Comment: Remove the `<button>` element.

Comment: Style your `a` tag like you would style the `button` and remove the `button` tag

Comment: If you want a link to look like a button, style it to look like a button. You should not have clickable elements nested. Other option is to make it a submit button, remove the link, add a form with the target and submit a form that takes you to the page.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I did that, but then the <a> style will apply to the other <li><a> elements above it which I don't want styled in the same way... 

I just wanna style the <a class="cta"> by it self.. can you advise me?

Comment: Use the specific selector, `a.cta` instead of `a` alone

Comment: If you're wanting a button then why are you using an anchor tag?  I think the clue is in the name...

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this: `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="button">Go to Stack Overflow</a>` instead of adding a button element inside of the anchor element.

```html
<body>
   <header>
      <nav>
         <ul class="nav_links">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="visit.html">Visit</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="button">Go to Stack Overflow</a>
   </header>
</body>

Example snippet:
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Hey!

That works in the validator 100%.

Comment: Oops, forgot to say..

The button styling I did in css does not apply to it anymore, what can I do now?

Comment: @PoTheBox - are we supposed to guess what your CSS is?  If you post your CSS in your OP this would improve our chances of answering your questions.